# How to use iframe widget into Workshop application

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop, foundry-slate

I'm trying to use the new iframe widget into workshop application with slate as input. (https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/widgets-iframe/index.html)
I do not understand how to use input / output and triggerable events into this widget.

I try a simple example with a string slate variable that i'm filling. I'm refering this variable as a key on the iframe widget but it's not working. I try also with sendMessage and getMessage actions in slate without success.
Do you know how to use the iframe widget and call slate variable ?
Thanks